# bootstrap navbar collapse not fuctioning and the answers on other questions didn't work

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a collapsable navbar with bootstrap, the nav does collapse but when I click on it it does not dropdown here is all the code I have in my index html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Honk</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="public/stylesheets/styles.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="public/stylesheets/custom.css">
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
       <img class="logo" src="public/images/honklogoo.png" alt="">
</div>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
       <li><a class="discrip" href="#">About</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Commuters</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Travelers</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">On Demand</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Safety</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Download</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav> 



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you dont have the the bootstrap js script in your html (you just have the css)

```
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

its working here: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/26/

btw, make sure you put it after your jquery script since bootstrap is dependent on jquery

Comment: Thank you, I totally overlooked that. I feel like an idiot, everything works fine now!